# VB script code not killing process in windows 7

Tags: vbscript, process, taskkill

I have a task in which whenever an application is running, and when I run upgrade of that application then the application should be removed from processes else it will throw licenses error as some of the licenses are attached to that application process.
Now I have created VB Script code to kill that particular application process and it is working fine in my local environment in windows 7.
But when I try to run same code on QA environment in windows 7 then process is not killing anyhow.
I tried many things like killing using administrator rights,created logs but not getting any hint where I am missing out.

Currently I am not having code if someone wants to check the VB Script code then I am updating the question after sometime.

If anyone have any information regarding this please suggest me...

Thanks in advance.

Refer below code:

```
Option Explicit

DIM FileObject

On Error Resume Next

set FileObject = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

FileObject.Run "TaskKill /F /IM Program1.exe", , True

FileObject.Run "TaskKill /F /IM Program2.exe", , True

FileObject.Run "TaskKill /F /IM Program3.exe", , True

FileObject.Run "TaskKill /F /IM Program4.exe", , True

FileObject.Run "TaskKill /F /IM Program5.exe", , True

FileObject.Run "TaskKill /F /IM Program6.exe", ,True
```

In above code, Program1 and Program6 are closed successfully from task manager but not other programs.

Note:- Above code is working fine when I explicitly running vb script file but when I include that script code in my upgrader exe then it is killing only program1 and program6.

Comment: How would we know as you've posted no details. Edit your question.

Comment: @Mark question is updated.

Comment: What user account is each task running as? If not an admin you can't close admin programs.

Comment: same user was used for launching an application and application that was killing..

Comment: What is the error message.

Comment: Get rid of this statement `On Error Resume Next` and re-execute your script again and post what error you will get !

Comment: @Mark I am not getting any error message but at last processes are still remaining in task manager.

Comment: @Hackoo ok will try and let you know...

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be because of 32 and 64 bit Processes.Try to handle it  use [Win32_Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

or you can try using a taskkill

eg

```
Dim myshell : myshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    ' Launch notepad '
    myshell.Run "notepad"
    WScript.Sleep 3000

    ' Kill notepad '
    myshell.Run("taskkill /im notepad.exe", , True)
```

or

```
 Dim myshell : Set myshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set Rt = myshell.Exec("Notepad") : wscript.sleep 4000 : Rt.Terminate
```

Not sure whether you are trying this as sample code is not provided